# Callback to html page after sending sms

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios

I have an html page in which i use a script on a link in order to open the native sms app on both Android and iOS with a preset text. My question is if there is any way, that after I send that sms, to be redirected to my html page. *without having to click on the back button*

Answer (score 1):

As per current architecture of Android and iOS, It is not possible to get back from where you have launched SMS application, SMS application has its own flow to handle within app, once application is closed then it will automatically get back to browser from where it launched.

Comment: I was afraid of this answer. As far as I researched I found the same thing, but I was hoping that I missed something and there is some *magic* that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `window.location="http://www.your_website.com/page.html;` to redirect to a specific page. Put it at the end of your SMS script execution!

Comment: doesn't seem to work. I should mention that I am accessing the website from my phone. after I click the link, the sms app launches. after I click send, I want the sms app to close(or to disappear ) and the browser to start again.